# Updating/Patching an event via the Google Calendar API as the Organizer of the event doesn't work

Tags: google-calendar-api

**Overview**: can't update or patch an event using the Google Calendar API as the organizer of the event (as documented here https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch).

To reproduce:

1. Create an event with user 1 (creator)
2. Pass ownership of the event to user 2 (organizer), so that the organizer of the event is not the same as the creator
3. call `PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<calendarId>/events/<eventId>` changing the summary or description (e.g. { "summary": "a new summary" }), using auth_token from user 2 (the organizer).

The response of the patch will be 200 SUCCESS, but the event itself is not changed.

4. making the same PATCH request in step 3 using the auth_token of user 1 (the creator) will both response 200 SUCCESS and do change the event.

Thank you if anyone can confirm this or has any other insights!

- Vinny Ly

Comment: I tried changing the owner to a new user and it needs to be accepted via a link first or if you've done it via `move` api, can you confirm if user2 is the actual organizer after executing it? user1 needs to have permissions first on user2's calendar before you can move it to them. If you changed the owner manually, you might need to accept the link first in the user2's gmail.

Comment: thanks for trying for me!  Yes I went through the whole process of changing the owner, and have user2 accept it via the email, so the event is all set up (with user1 as creator and user 2 as organizer) when I tried the PATCH request.

Comment: That is weird. Mine succeeded without an issue when user2 did the patch request after the change of owner. Can you try updating the summary [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch?apix=true)?

Comment: Thank you for checking that for me.  If it works for you then it must be something else.  Maybe a permission thing on the calendar like you said.  Let me do some more experimentation.  I really appreciate you investigating and confirming with me!

Comment: If you ever find the cause and have fixed it, feel free to post it as answer so that other users will find it useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok, I was mistaken and made a few bad choices when testing.

I got the users (creator and organizer) mixed up in Step 4 during my testing and Nazia was right, the organizer of the event will be the only person that can patch/update the event once ownership is transferred, unless permissions is given to Guests to allow editing of the event (check the "Modify event" checkbox under "Guest permissions" when editing the event as the organizer).

Even the creator of the event will not have permissions (API or otherwise) to edit the event unless that permission is given.

Comment: Good to see you figured it out.